# $\sum_{0\leq{k}<50}\binom{100}{2k+1}5^k \equiv r\pmod{ 2^{99}}$ where $0 \leq{r} < 2^{99}$, find $r$.

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, modular-arithmetic

$$\sum_{0\leq{k}<50}\binom{100}{2k+1}5^k \equiv r\pmod{ 2^{99}}$$ where $0 \leq{r} < 2^{99}$, find $r$.

This is a question that was posed in last year's LIMIT competition conducted by the Indian Statistical Institute. Full solutions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The answer is $$633825300114114700748351602588=2^2\cdot 330623\cdot 479265886004690161262489$$ which looks really strange

Comment: i did some searching and found that the given answer is zero, however they didn't provide any working

Comment: The answer is not $0$, as checked by [brute force](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Mod%5BSum%5BBinomial%5B100%2C+2+k%2B1%5D+5%5Ek%2C+%7Bk%2C1%2C49%7D%5D%2C2%5E99%5D)

Comment: @MaximilianJanisch To explain what is happening, the current answer is $2^{99} -100$, likely because the indexing in the original problem was supposed to include $ k = 0$. But then again, the problem states $ 0 < r < 2^{99}$, so maybe that was intentional.

Comment: @CalvinLin Thanks, there is clearly something off with the problem statement here since $0<r<2^{99}$ is also wrong if the correct answer should be $r=0$

Comment: i made an error, it should be $\sum_{0 \leq{r} < 2^{99}} $and the same for the condition on r

Comment: OP you need to be clear and precise when writing out your question on here, as people put a decent amount of thought into their answers.

Comment: My apologies, i'll make sure to do so now onwards

Answer (score 4):

Note: The problem was subsequently edited from $ 0 < k < 50$ to $0 \leq k \leq 50$, and from $ 0 < r < 2^{99}$ to $ 0 \leq r < 2^{99}$.

Following the hinted solution below (which I'm too lazy to edit), the answer is $0$.

---

**Hint:** $$\sum_{k=0} ^ {100} \binom{100}{k}\sqrt{5}^kx^k  = (1 + \sqrt{5}x)^{100} $$

Now set $ x = 1, -1$.
How can we get (close to) the expression in the question?
Note that you might be off by 1 term due to $ 0 < k < 50$ (Look at $ k = 0 $ closely).

The sum in the problem is thus

> $\frac{ (1 + \sqrt{ 5} )^{100} - (1 - \sqrt{ 5} )^{100} } { \sqrt{5} } - 100$

Now, prove by induction that if $ ( 1 + \sqrt{5} ) ^ n = a_n + b_n \sqrt{5}$, then $ 2^{n-1} \mid a_n, 2^{n-1} \mid b_n$.
In particular, for $ n = 100$, both terms are multiples of $ 2^ {99}$.

Hence, the answer is

> $2^{99} -100$

This agrees with Wolfram.